# What happens when I buy a stock?

Tags: trading, robinhood

I am curious about what happens under the hood when I buy one share of APPL at market price on robinhood.

1. What happens if there is someone else on robinhood is selling one share of APPL at the same time. Is my order "consumed" within robinhood internally?
2. As robinhood profits from PFOF, my order will be sent to market makers. Does robinhood send my order to one market maker first, or is the order sent to multiple market makers? Won't I get two shares instead of one?
3. Suppose AAPL was listed on multiple exchanges. Is my order sent to all the exchanges and how is the double selling prevented. As people on different exchanges might see my order and decide to sell at the same time.

Comment: It's explained on the [website](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/stock-order-routing/). Since Robin Hood mostly uses market makers, you hardly ever have direct contact with an exchange either way.

Comment: And I believe there are past answers here regarding how sellers and buyers are matched up.

Comment: @keshlam - Your comment would be more helpful if you linked to one of those answers.